# UITextView text scaling issue , which is having different font styles attributes

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, scaling, nsattributedstring

[image][image]Simply I was trying to make a draggle, scaleable `UITextView`, I am done with **dragging** and **scaling** using single font in textView. But the problem is, when I am trying to add different font style with different text ranges in textView then I don't know how to **calculate font size** after scaling textview with finger.
Because each custom font has different dimensions.

**Here is code which I was using to increasing and decreasing font size while `UITextView` scaling.**

```
 func updateTextFont(edgeInsets:UIEdgeInsets) {
        self.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: (edgeInsets.top * frame.height),
                                               left: (edgeInsets.left * frame.width),
                                               bottom: (edgeInsets.bottom * frame.height),
                                               right: (edgeInsets.right * frame.width))
        if (self.text.isEmpty || self.bounds.size.equalTo(CGSize.zero)) { return;         }
        let textViewSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.width , height: self.frame.height);
        let fixedWidth = textViewSize.width;
        let expectSize = self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
        var expectFont = self.font
        if (expectSize.height > textViewSize.height) {
            while (self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height > textViewSize.height && (self.font!.pointSize > CGFloat(1))) {
                expectFont = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize - 0.1)
                self.font = expectFont
            }
        }
        else {
            while (self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height < textViewSize.height && (self.font!.pointSize < CGFloat(1000))) {
                expectFont = self.font
                self.font = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize + 0.1)
            }
            self.font = expectFont
        }
    }
```

so here is the situation I want to convert this method for `NSAttributeString`, I can't assign single font to `textView`. I want to scale **attributeString** with textView bounds.
See in the SS , on first SS, I calculated the box size using attributed string, in the next SS I change the box size but how to make attribute string fit in updated box. this is the problem I am facing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want exactly value of a size of a font. But if can use nearest values for fonts, you will solve this task with algorithm.

1. Increase or decrease sizes of all fonts. [You can enumerate all attributes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1412461-enumerateattribute) of the string with

   func enumerateAttribute(_ attrName: NSAttributedString.Key,
   in enumerationRange: NSRange,
   options opts: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions = [],
   using block: (Any?, NSRange, UnsafeMutablePointer) -> Void)

And increase or decrease sizes of fonts based on scale.
2. After that you [can calculate size of the string](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1529154-boundingrect) with:

```
func boundingRect(with size: CGSize, 
      options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [], 
      context: NSStringDrawingContext?) -> CGRect
```

3. Repeat this for other sizes of fonts.

If you calculate rects for different font sizes, you will take nearest value for bounds of the TextView.

As I remember, you can calculate sizes for different fonts in background on parallel threads.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your solution @Andrew, let me try with this ,I will let you know soon.

Comment: please check the Screenshot once.

Comment: I just want the font size according to box size for attribute string.